# .hide("slow") is synchronous or Asynchronous method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, synchronous

As we know `$.ajax()` Is a asynchronous method ,  beacuse next statement starts executing before `ajax()` method is fully executed and 'ajax()' keep doing his stuff parallelly ,And `hide()` is a Synchronous method, because it immediately hides the element  and  next statement will execute when `hide()` really done his whole task, But I am really confused  in the case of `hide("slow")`. It seems Asynchronous but I read,  it sets the timer in browser and everything happen automatically(now `hide("slow")` is  doing nothing parallelly) so in a way , It has also been done its whole task before the next statement start executing ,So   `hide("slow")` also seems a  synchronous  method ,

I am very confused about this  Synchronous Asynchronous concept

Can someone help me to understand this concept  ?

Comment: There is no difference between `.ajax`, `.hide`, and `.hide(slow)`. They are all functions that trigger some kind of asynchronous ongoing operation that will finish after the function invocation finishes. Both `ajax` and `hide` accept callbacks that execute when the asynchronous operation completes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> .hide(“slow”) is synchronous or Asyncronous method

The *call* to the method is synchronous, but it starts an asynchronous process. So we would normally, loosely, call it an "asynchronous method" (in this case, where you're giving it a duration argument).

When you call `hide("slow")`, you synchronously tell jQuery to *start* the process of of hiding the element slowly over time. The process of actually doing that takes place asynchronously, after the initial call to `hide` is complete. (This is also true of `ajax`: The method itself is synchronous, but the process it starts — doing the XMLHttpRequest — continues asynchronously.)

Typically if the work of the method is completed *during* the call to it, we call it a synchronous method, but if it only *starts* work that completes later, we call it an asynchronous method. Technically the method itself isn't asynchronous, just the overall process that it initiates, but...

[`hide`](http://api.jquery.com/hide) itself, of course, is both a synchronous and asynchronous method depending on what argument(s) you pass it: If you call it with no duration (`.hide()`), it's synchronous; if you call it with a duration (`.hide("slow")`, `.hide(400)`), it's asynchronous.

Comment: then their is no method is asynchronous only the effect is asynchronous, Can you name of any asynchronous method ?

Comment: @beginner There are none, in the same sense that all function invocations are synchronous in that the flow of control enters them and does not return until the function returns. This question is more about a misapplication of those terms, than anything else.

Comment: @beginner: It's an interesting semantic point, I've tried to clarify the wording above.

Comment: THANKS, It was very helpful sir, now the concept is very much clear to me

Answer (score 1):

Also, for your another question,

> I am very confused about this Synchronous Asynchronous concept Can
>   someone help me to understand this concept ?

When you debug a line of code and the line is not passing to the next line until the execution completes, its synchronous operation since the same thread is performing the complete execution of the code.

On the other hand, if debugging is passing to the next line before the actual operation completes then its asynchronous operation since as in your question above, the hide & animation are performed in the background with different thread while the main thread started executing the next line.

Hope it clarifies your question above.